# Convert Hierarchical Data to JSON tree using PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I have `PostgreSQL` function (tree structure),i need to convert the output to `json` tree format.

my `PostgreSQL` function

```
RETURN QUERY
WITH RECURSIVE manger_hierarchy(e_id,e_name,m_name,m_id) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        e.emp_id,e.emp_name,
        m.emp_name AS man_name,e.emp_man_id 
    FROM emp_det e 
    LEFT JOIN emp_det m ON e.emp_man_id=m.emp_id
    WHERE e.emp_id = id
    UNION
    SELECT 
        rp.emp_id,rp.emp_name,
        mh.e_name AS manager,rp.emp_man_id
    FROM manger_hierarchy mh
    INNER JOIN emp_det rp ON mh.e_id = rp.emp_man_id
)
SELECT h.e_id,h.e_name,h.m_name,h.m_id
FROM manger_hierarchy h;
```

and my `php` scrip is

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`
`$dbconn=pg_connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test1 user=someuser password=somepass');`
`$x=$_GET['id'];`
`$result=pg_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM employe_manager_details($x)");`
`$y=pg_fetch_all($result);`
`echo json_encode($y, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`
`pg_close($dbconn);`

my current result 
`[
    {
        "e_id": "4",
        "e_name": "john",
        "e_manager": "steve",
        "e_man_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "e_id": "8",
        "e_name": "jake",
        "e_manager": "john",
        "e_man_id": "4"
    },
    {
        "e_id": "9",
        "e_name": "wilson",
        "e_manager": "john",
        "e_man_id": "4"
    }
]`

expect result

`[
    {
        "e_id": "4",
        "e_name": "john",
        "e_manager": "steve",
        "e_man_id": "2"
    },
                {
                "e_id": "8",
                "e_name": "jake",
                "e_manager": "john",
                "e_man_id": "4"
                },
                {
                "e_id": "9",
                "e_name": "wilson",
                "e_manager": "john",
                "e_man_id": "4"
                }
]`

Comment: whats the difference in both the result, aren't they same

Comment: can you point me where exactly the difference in your current and expected result?

Comment: i need joson tree output.. e_id 4 has two childs.. the childs suold be intented

Answer (score 0):

Your rendering this to html I'm guessing. Is that correct? Wrap the output in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>'.json_encode($y, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with your query then. I don't have the time at the moment to figure it out but whatever your returning from the db is not what you expect thus json_encode is not returning what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't touched pgsql for years, so not sure if there's a function to get the returned data keyed by the values of a given column. But with all the results in a php variable, you could do this:

```
$results = pg_fetch_all($result);
$ordered_results = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $ordered_results[$result['e_man_id']][] = $result;
}
echo json_encode($ordered_results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

That would include the "e_man_id" values in the first-level of the json returned, and values will be nested as you describe you expect them.

I don't know of any option in json_encode() that would let you do that automatically.

Comment: Sorry, im not getting expected result, thank you the consideration